# how calling the images in a folder with php

Tags: php, reference

I want to ask about calling the images in a folder with php

The first I've made ​​a file to declare the image url

```
$url_folder_gambar = 'http://localhost/mysite/assets/img/';
```

I then call the php but the picture did not come out. what's wrong?

```
<img src="<?php echo $url_folder_gambar . people.png?>"
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a syntax error. Try this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $url_folder_gambar;?>people.png" />
```

Comment: if you put the url: http://localhost/mysite/assets/img/people.png into a browser, does it show then?

Comment: Not sure, can you show the HTML that is being displayed in the browser (use inspect element) and the EXACT php code that you are currently using

Comment: thanks it works!
I have forgotten to include file variable
thanks helpfull

Answer (score 0):

`$url_folder_gambar` path of the image file,  some thing like `http://domain/path/imagefolder/`

```
<img src="<?php echo $url_folder_gambar;?>people.png" >
```

OR

```
<img src="<?php echo $url_folder_gambar.'people.png';?>" >
```

Check browser code view source using `ctrl+u`, check the file path, and copy the `source` url and pasted into the borwser, whether it is rendered or not, If not there is no file in that location.